# No puedo entrar a phpMyAdmin 4.8.5

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, apache

Al intentar entrar a phpMyAdmin me aparece el siguiente error.

```
Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS.
```

He intentado varias soluciones que he encontrado por internet pero ninguna ha funcionado. Tiene arreglo o tengo que usar una versión anterior?.

Estoy utilizando laragon en Windows, tengo la version 7.4.11 de php, estoy utilizando el navegador Chrome.

Lo raro es que en incognito si que funciona, y con firefox también.
He intentado acceder con https y me da el mismo fallo.

Comment: Danos mas datos. Versión actual, tipo de servidor, sistema operativo, si has cambiado de servidor....Adivinos no somos. Dinos que soluciones has intentado, para no caer en lo mismo.

Comment: Ya he probado todo lo que había en esa pregunta@MikelFerreiro, @Emerita Versión 4.8.5,  apache, Windows 10, he probado todas las soluciones que he encontrado en SO y del github, donde aparece reportado el bug.

Comment: ¿Intentaste usando `https` para acceder? Mira lo que te dice el mensaje... *Tal vez usted está utilizando HTTP en lugar de HTTPS.* Aparte de eso, nunca está de más limpiar la caché, probar con otro navegador o con otro equipo, etc.

Comment: @MikelFerreiro aquí no se da *like*. Se vota a favor (o en contra) y se marcan respuestas como aceptadas. Saludos. (Este comentario se destruirá en el momento oportuno).

Comment: Danos el enlace al bug, dinos versión del apache, versión del php (phpmyadmin tira con php) Has migrado de una versión anterior a esta?

Comment: Este es el enlace al bug https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14184

Comment: Estoy utilizando laragon, con php 7.2.11, es una instalación nueva, @A.Cedano nose como utilizar https estoy en local.

Comment: Según indican en todos lados lo que puedes hacer es borrar las cookies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49811804/phpmyadmin-failed-to-set-session-cookie-maybe-you-are-using-http-instead-of-htt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he conseguido que funcione ni con la version 4.7 de `phpmyadmin`,al final he cambiado `auth_type` en el `config.inc.php` por `config` y ya funciona correctamente.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```